# Getting data from Spring MVC in Angular JS in the initial view call

Tags: javascript, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to Angular JS, I have created a Spring MVC web application with Angular JS, I know that from view we can call REST services from Angular JS using resource, restangular, http , But say in Spring form the Controller a view is been triggered and for loading the datas through angular within the view again a REST call from angular is been called from view to the server and gets the datas thereafter for loading, Instead is there any way to pass the json object while triggering the view from Spring controller to the Angular JS at the first time itself.

[image]

I have done a similar thing, its working fine but don't know whether its a good approach or not.

**Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/getemployee")
public ModelAndView helloWord(){
   JSONArray employeeJsonArray = // contains all the information of the employee
   return new ModelAndView("employee", "employee",employeeJsonArray);
}
```

**employee.jsp**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.employee = [];
    $scope.loadData = function(employee)
    {
        $scope.employee = JSON.parse(employee);
    };
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
{{loadData('${employee}')}}

 <input type="text" ng-value="employee[0].name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you asking whether you can supply the json data with the page, like you would with a traditional request/response application?

Comment: yes, but data needs to be passed from the server with the initial view call itself

Comment: You could use `ng-init`, I'll write up a short answer

Comment: Excellent question! I fav. to future reference.

Comment: However with the above scenario , there could be flickering , with the content being displayed momentarily .
Hence the Use of ng-cloak .

<span ng-cloak>{{payCntrl.loadContactAddress('${contactAddress}')}}</span>

With the CSS :

[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular really shines when you use it in a "single" page application, so I would suggest using it as you suggested in your "existing approach" as it moves you closer to a single page app design, however, if you are just trying to get some of the features of Angular in an existing request/response application, then you could send your html payload with the data in `ng-init` as this [page](http://jaketrent.com/post/pass-values-from-page-to-angular/) demonstrates.  It's a RoR example, but I think the point is clear.  I think it is a bit of hack, but should get the job done.

```
   <body ng-init="angularVariable = ${variableFromServer}">
     html/angular ...
   </body>
```

Comment: in my application where should i call that

Comment: otherwise if we are using the existing approach as shown in the picture, two server calls is been made right, instead if we can load the data at the initial call itself we can prevent two calls right

Comment: True, 2 server calls are made.  Initial request/response to render the page and 1 more for the data. It depends on your ultimate goal.  If you are trying to bolt on features to a legacy app, you could use ng-init.  If you working on a new app, I would suggest going the single page application route.

Comment: Getting `Error: [$parse:ueoe]` this is my code `<body ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="employee = ${employee}">`

Comment: Is employee a json payload or a java object?

Comment: yes just like as shown in my code `JSONArray employeeJsonArray = // contains all the information of the employee
   return new ModelAndView("employee", "employee",employeeJsonArray);`

Comment: Can you log the json array returned by your controller and try passing  that directly into the ng-init as a string.  i.e. ng-init="your json array" and see if you still get the same error

Comment: from the controller i am passing the json object as string, in the angular it should be parsed to JSON right

Comment: In the controller when we do like `new ModelAndView("employee", "employee",employeeJsonArray);` the employeeJsonArray json will be converted to string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55277/discussion-between-dspies-and-alex-man).

Comment: I am getting Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 13 of the expression [ on using this

Answer (score 2):

I recently switched to using angular, the beauty of it is you can ditch jsp's entirely and just have static html as the frontend. Served as a static resource by spring.

To initially populate your form/tables/whatever - lots of different options do it in javascript/angular.  But its nice to keep your view seperate from your controllers (ie don't use jsp's).

Comment: They are completely ditched except for something to return contextPath for service call root paths.  If sometimes have my app.js interpretedby a freemarker servlet and set some config variable to base: '${base}'

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for get user logging,

```
<input type="text" ng-model ="currentLoging" ng-init= "currentLoging='${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}'" />
```