# Providing Data From Spring MVC to AnjularJS in the initial view call

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to Angular JS, I have created a Spring MVC web application with Angular JS, I know that from view we can call REST services from Angular JS using resource, restangular, http , But say in Spring form the Controller a view is been triggered and for loading the datas through angular within the view again a REST call from angular is been called from view to the server and gets the datas thereafter for loading, Instead is there any way to pass the json object while triggering the view from Spring controller to the Angular JS at the first time itself.!

I tried this code which i found in StackOverflow with the similar problem and with my modified approach making use of "ng-init",, but i could'nt find the solution to it yet..
    [2]: [Getting data from Spring MVC in Angular JS in the initial view call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106610/getting-data-from-spring-mvc-in-angular-js-in-the-initial-view-call/24106784#24106784][2])

```
SpringController

@RequestMapping(value="/BillingHome")
   public ModelAndView redirectToMainHome(HttpServletRequest  req,HttpServletResponse res) throws JSONException
   {
      String msg="\"JSON Testing\",\"JsonTesting\"";
     /*  JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(msg);*/

      HashMap<String,String> hdata=new HashMap<String,String>();
      hdata.put("JSONTesting", "JSONTESTING");

      Gson gson= new Gson();
        String jobj=gson.toJson(hdata);

        System.out.println(jobj);

        return new ModelAndView("Billing/BillingHome","jobj",jobj);

   }


BillingLogin.jsp

<html ng-app="loginApp" ng-init="JSONfromServer=${jobj}">
<head>
<title>Billing..</title>

</head>
<body ng-contorller="loginCtrl">
<%
  String usnamefrmSession;
  usnamefrmSession=session.getAttribute("username").toString();
%>


<center><h2>Hello <%=usnamefrmSession%> ..! <br>Inside Billing Home           Successfully..</h2></h1></center>


<input type="text" ng-model="JSONfromServer">


</body>
</html>
```

But when i run this application data, the input field which has to provide the json data from spring is placed empty.
please help me out with the suggestions and solution if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using controllers and making use of some customs helped me to get the nearest answer